# how to call event of delphi dll at c#?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

**Delphi7 test.dll**

```
unit DLLFunction;
interface
uses
  Sysutils, classes,  Dialogs;

type
  TEvent = procedure(index, status, percent: integer) of object; stdcall;
  IMyDll = interface
  ['{42C845F8-F45C-4BC7-8CB5-E76658262C4A}']
    procedure SetEvent(const value: TEvent); stdcall;
  end;

  TMyDllClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyDll)
  public
    procedure SetEvent(const value: TEvent); stdcall;
  end;

  procedure CreateDelphiClass(out intf: IMyDll); stdcall;

implementation
procedure TMyDllClass.SetEvent(const value: TEvent); stdcall;
begin
  if Assigned (value) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Event call');
    value(1,2,3);
  end;
end;
exports
  createDelphiClass;
end.
```

**C# source**

```
// event
  public delegate void TEvent(int index, int status, int percent);

  [ComImport, Guid("42C845F8-F45C-4BC7-8CB5-E76658262C4A"),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
  public interface IMyDll
  {
    // event
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
    void SetEvent([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]TEvent eventCallback);

  }

  class TestInterface
  {
    const string dllPath = "testDelphiDll.DLL";

    [DllImport(dllPath, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void CreateDelphiClass(out IMyDll dll);

    public IMyDll getDelphiInterface()
    {
      IMyDll mydll = null;
      CreateDelphiClass(out mydll);

      return mydll;
    }
  }
```

**and then use in c#**

```
  TestInterface tInterface = new TestInterface();
  delphi = tInterface.getDelphiInterface();

  delphi.SetEvent(delegate(int index, int status, int percent)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("index: " + index.ToString() + "\nstatus: " + status.ToString() + " \npercent: " + percent.ToString());
  });
```

**the result**

index: -19238192731

status: 1

percent: 2

and then crash application.
  exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in DLLCallTest.exe.
>
> TIP: You attempted to read or write protected memory. In most cases,
>   this indicates that other memory is corrupted.

I think this is not a problem, but why occured this exception and wrong parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Delphi declaration of `TEvent` is `of object`. That doesn't match your C#. The `of object` method type is a double pointer holding both the instance reference and the code address. Your C# delegate is a single pointer with the code address.

Remove the `of object` and your program will work.

Comment: if i use 'of object', then how to use delegate in c#?

Comment: There is no supported way. You have to hack.